# id_token/Identity token claims difference between implicit vs any other flow

Tags: .net, identityserver4

Why there is a difference in identity token claims when using implicit or any other grant type? Is this by specification or am I doing something wrong? Any help to understand this behavior will be highly appreciated.

When I use implicit grant type with id_token response, I get all the claims added into the scope from client that identity server is protecting. 
But when I use hybrid grant type or code grant type, most of the claims (email and phone) are missing from Identity token. But I can see email and phone in scope list with in access token.
Using access token I can hit userinfo endpoint to get all the info in scope.

Comment: In this case a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the flow used and the identity provider implementation, the content of the tokens may vary.

The [OpendId Connect Specs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) say:

> **3.3.3.6.  ID Token**
>
> When using the Hybrid Flow, the contents of an ID Token returned from the Token Endpoint are the same as for an ID Token
> returned from the Authorization Endpoint, as defined in Section
> 3.3.2.11, with the exception of the differences specified in this section.
>
> If an ID Token is returned from both the Authorization Endpoint and
> from the Token Endpoint, which is the case for the response_type
> values code id_token and code id_token token, the iss and sub Claim
> Values MUST be identical in both ID Tokens. All Claims about the
> Authentication event present in either SHOULD be present in both. If
> either ID Token contains Claims about the End-User, any that are
> present in both SHOULD have the same values in both. Note that the OP
> MAY choose to return fewer Claims about the End-User from the
> Authorization Endpoint, for instance, for privacy reasons. The at_hash
> and c_hash Claims MAY be omitted from the ID Token returned from the
> Token Endpoint even when these Claims are present in the ID Token
> returned from the Authorization Endpoint, because the ID Token and
> Access Token values returned from the Token Endpoint are already
> cryptographically bound together by the TLS encryption performed by
> the Token Endpoint.

And if you get the Access Token from both endpoints (Authorize and Token) they can be different:

> **3.3.3.8.  Access Token**
>
> If an Access Token is returned from both the Authorization Endpoint
> and from the Token Endpoint, which is the case for the response_type
> values code token and code id_token token, their values MAY be the
> same or they MAY be different. Note that different Access Tokens might
> be returned be due to the different security characteristics of the
> two endpoints and the lifetimes and the access to resources granted by
> them might also be different.